# Angular app navigation not applying when serving app in expressjs

Tags: node.js, angular, express, navigation

I have an Angular 7 app, that is server over expressjs.

The app serving part of the server is like so:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   console.log(`sending...`);
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
```

It's very simple: When I navigate to localhost:PORT I get the base page of the angular app, which is a login page.

Angular's routing is like so:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: LoginComponent},
{ path: 'query', component: QueryComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard] },
{ path: '**', pathMatch:'full', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

When I serve angular via `ng serve`, and I try to navigate to any unauthorized page, like: `http://localhost:4200/anyPage` or `http://localhost:4200/query` and I get redirected to the login page or to the authGuard I created.

This is the behaviour that I want - any user how try to navigate to the query part of my app and dosen't pass the authGuard, will be redirected to the login page, and any user that is lost and enters a weird url, will be redirected back to the base page.

Where the issue?

When I serve my app with express, It works only when I enter the root url: `http://localhost:PORT`, and I got my base page served.

When I try to navigate to any other url, like: `http://locahost:PORT/query` or `http://localhostPORT/anyPage` I get an GET error: `Cannot GET /query`.

How do I make angular's routing take place when I serve it via expressjs?
I read [This answer regarding nagular routes and nodejs route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201693/mean-angular-routes-over-riding-nodejs-routes), and I must ask:
Is the only way to solve my issue is to define authGuard to each page in angular so that nodejs/express will allways redirect to angular's base page and angular must hande everything from there (and get errors whenever I try to navigate to any url that is not defined in express)?

Is there is no way that some of the navigation will be handeled by express?

If express "knows" only to navigate to the base url in angular, what is the point of defining routing in angular? When the route that I defined in angular, like: `path:'/query'` comes into effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `app.get('*')` to direct all request to `index.html`. This will also direct static assets, so you have to add a `app.use()`:

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  console.log(`sending...`);
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port);
```

Comment: Hi, but then again - express allways redirects to angular's base page. When angular's routing that I defiend comes into effect? only when the user navigated with the app, and never by navigating in the browser? What if I don't want to navigate to the app base page? is ther a way to achieve that?

Comment: it doesn't redirect at all. It just serves the `index.html` file without altering the requesting url. Did you try my solution?

Comment: I have tried it, and it does redirect to the base page, but I have 2 issues: 
1) It always handels get request and serves the base page, but I have some get request paths for API purposes (like: app.get('/checkAuth')).
2) If express always serves the base page, what is the point of defining routes in angular? for internal app use only?

Comment: @yishain11 1: add a `app.get('/checkAuth')` before the `*` route. And for any API path there might be. Or better would be to make the API a separate app listening on a different port.

2. Yes, routing in angular is used for internal use. This way it can be a SPA (single page application), and have normal URLs. It also enables the possibility to use route guards, lazy loading, resolving etc.