# Is there a way to override Angular router using Node.js routing - Just for a specific path?

Tags: html, node.js, angular, exception, router

I currently have a service which is being served through Node to the user, and is using Angular's router.
Everything works great, except for one thing: I want to use Node's router for one specific path instead of Angular's router.
How can this be achieved?

As a temporary solution, I have been trying using CORS, which was successful in a way, but is sure not a solution that can be used.

I saw this Stackoverflow post:
[MEAN - Angular routes over-riding NodeJS routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201693/mean-angular-routes-over-riding-nodejs-routes)

But it seems to maily target Angular's router.

The incoming request for a specific path (example: POST request to "/specificpath"), should be handled by Node.js, the rest of the requests should be handled with Angular's router.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you redirect all incoming traffic to the index.html file, so that Angular will take care of the routing:

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/public/index.html');
});
```

Since this is treated as registered middleware, you can simply add a route that should not be send to Angular by specifying routes the way you usually do in node.js:

```
app.get('/specificpath', yourController.yourMethod);
```

So the complete code example is:

```
app.get('/specificpath', yourController.yourMethod);
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/public/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Thank you Julien. Will that work defining the specific path first, then the static middleware as below? `app.use(express.static('dist/'))`

Comment: I guess so, just try it out. I am not able to test it, sorry